# Unable to complete the code for Tkinter. Please check the below code for the password

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

Unable to complete the below code given below. I'm trying to create a pop up for enter the password. If the password is correct then it should run the code completely. If the password is wrong then it should give the same popup and to enter the correct password.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()

def myClick():
    password = "sunny567"
    get = e.get()
    if password == get:
        myLabel = Label(root, text=get)
        myLabel.pack()
    else:
        myLabel = Label(root, text="Entered Password is wrong. Please try again.")
        myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Enter the password", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Code continued

Comment: The indentation seems very broken. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Edited the code once please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def myClick():
    password = "sunny567"
    get = e.get()
    if password == get:
        LabelVar.set(get)
    else:
        LabelVar.set("Entered Password is wrong. Please try again.")
        e.delete(0, 'end')

e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()

LabelVar = StringVar()
myLabel = Label(root, textvariable=LabelVar)
myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Enter the password", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Instead of create every time a new label you can set one and change his variable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add *messagebox* to create pop ups. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox 

root = Tk()

def myClick():
    password = "sunny567"
    get = e.get()
    if password == get:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Congrats","code completely")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Incorrect Password","Enterd Password is wrong. Please try again")
        e.delete(0,END)
        
e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()

LabelVar = StringVar()
myLabel = Label(root, textvariable=LabelVar)
myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Enter the password", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you want something more, let me know.